# How to add Percentile in Spring WebFlux metrics

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I am trying to add Percentile (like 0.95) into a webflux method and have it exported through `/actuator/prometheus`.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    MyClassRepository repository;

    Mono<MyClass> getMyClass(@NonNull String someId) {
        return repository.findById(someId)
                .name("MyService.getMyClass.time").metrics();
    }
}
```

With `.name("MyService.getMyClass.time").metrics();` I am getting COUNT, TOTAL_TIME and MAX but I would need Percentile too. I am using Spring boot 2.7.5. I am not using any Custom Bean to generate metrics.
How do I add percentile?

I asked ChatGPT and got non-working solution below.
`
@Configuration
public class PercentileMeterRegistry {

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<SimpleMeterRegistry> customizer() {
    return registry -> registry.config()
            .meterFilter(new MeterFilter() {
                public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(
                        @NonNull DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
                    return DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
                            .percentiles(0.95, 0.99) // Add the desired percentiles
                            .build()
                            .merge(config);
                }
            });
}`
```